# Injecting angular-resource after npm install

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular-resource

I'm trying to implement `angular-resource` in my MEAN application. I ran `npm install angular-resource --save` and now I want to inject it using

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'angular-resource'])
```

but I get the typical `Error: [$injector:modulerr]`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the module is `ngResource`, not `angular-resource`.

Comment: Also, how are you requiring the files. Is it just with script tags, or is it with a module loader?

Comment: So it's with neither. I have `angular-resource/` in my `node_modules/` directory but I do not have any `<script src="angular resource...etc">` and no `var ngresource = require('angular-resource')` anywhere.

Comment: Well that's your problem. You need to require the module just like you're requiring angular. So however you're requiring the angular.js file, you then need to put under it the angular-resource.js file.

Comment: I had the impression that running `npm install angular-resource --save` would allow me to simply inject it into my app like so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105750/discussion-between-oceansonpluto-and-gh0st).